# What are the consequences for a family fight in the US?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, liability, tort, family

If a mother (senior) first tries to slap her daughter (30+ yrs old), but the mother missed, and then the daughter grabs the clothes her mom is wearing, and slams her mother against the wall, what kind of law is violated? What are the consequences if a mother sues her daughter or the daughter sues her mother?

Comment: The consequences are a lot of legal bills and heightened domestic animosity.  It would be more productive, and likely cheaper, to seek counseling to learn how to work out your differences peacefully.

Comment: Juvenile tag removed after the clarification that this scuffle involved two adults. The legal analysis is much more complicated when the daughter is a juvenile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most often, as a practical matter, this incident would not be brought to the attention of law enforcement or the courts, and hurt feelings and a bruise or two would be the only consequences.

In the case of adults, this would probably legally constitute assault (in the narrow sense) in the first instance, and battery, in the second. The exact name of the offense varies from state to state, but those are the common law names for these offenses.

These are both crimes (usually petty offenses or misdemeanors since there is no serious bodily harm), and also torts that could form the basis of lawsuits, although the damages would be nominal or nearly so. This could also be the basis for either party to seek a protection order/restraining order (the formal terminology varies from state to state).

A criminal "disorderly conduct" charge would also be common in these circumstances. "Abuse of an elderly person" could be a charge depending upon the age of the mother. A "domestic violence" criminal charge would be less likely but would be possible in some states (and more significant, as a domestic violence charge results in a lifetime prohibition on owning a firearm as a collateral consequence).

Authorities pressed charges in [a recent case](https://www.denverpost.com/2024/01/10/lauren-boebert-ex-husband-jayson-arrested-assault-restaurant-fight-colorad/) involving the ex-husband of a Colorado member of Congress and his son this week.

Any of the potential legal consequences would probably take place in state court.

> What are the consequences if a mother sues her daughter or the
> daughter sues her mother?

A lawsuit happens and the court process runs its course. If a money judgment is entered for one or both of them, the judgment could be collected in a court process. Also, the mother and daughter are likely to become estranged after this happens.

Comment: If the mother sues the daughter for elderly abuse, and the daughter defends by saying the mother tried to hit her first, and so she shoves her mother onto the wall due to self-defense, how would the court process play out?

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld Elder abuse would be a criminal charge rather than the basis of a civil lawsuit. How it was resolved would depend upon how the judge (in a bench trial) or jury evaluates the facts and circumstances after hearing all of the evidence. It could come out either way.

Comment: @HelloDarkWorld under *some* conditions, the person that is victim of battery *might* have a case of self defense, under others not. That is highly fact specific.